# Excel VBA Repeat same value for 3 row multiple time

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have code below for display value even and odd row base on specific column criteria.
But how to display 3 different value from 3 row and continues looping that 3 value for another 90 row or more. At the end, each value have repeated 30 times.

```
Sub OddRowAlert()
With Range("B16:B100") ' working
    .Formula = "=IF(A16="""","""",IF((MOD(ROW(B16),2)),""=+SEK!$I$6"",""=+SEK!$K$6""))"
    .Formula = .Value
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean having different formula on three consecutive cells of the same column and fill down this range formulas? If yes, please try my code answer. If not, please better explain what is your real need...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, code please:

```
Sub testFillDownThreeRows()
  Dim sh As Worksheet
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
   sh.Range("A2").formula = "=Today()"  'use here what formulas you need
   sh.Range("A3").formula = "=Today()+1"
   sh.Range("A4").formula = "=Now()"
   sh.Range("A2:A4").AutoFill Destination:=sh.Range("A2:A21"), Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub
```

Comment: There is 1 problem, if I use to refer a cell, it's can't maintain the same cell, but it flow to next cell. Example if I refer cell with value "21","22","23", then the next value is "24","25","26". It's can't maintain "21","22","23"

Comment: @xdenama: It is a matter of absolute address. If I do  not see the formula you use, it is difficult to give you a good piece of advice. In principle, you must replace a cell like "C24" with "C$24"...